# retornar lista en reduce python

Tags: python

tengo una duda al momento de retornar una lista como resultado de un reduce. El código funciona con un for:

```
def notengo(lista_persona1, lista_persona2):
   lista_respuesta = []
   for num1 in lista_persona1:
      if num1 not in lista_persona2:
          lista_respuesta.append(num1)
   return lista_respuesta
```

Pero ahora quiero retornar esto en un reduce:

```
def notengo(lista_persona1, lista_persona2):
   return reduce(lambda acc, num: acc.append(num) if num not in lista_persona2 else acc, lista_persona1, list([]))
```

Pero me da un error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a lograr el objetivo. Si es cierto que ya funciona con el for, pero me encantaría aprenderlo a realizar usando reduce. De antemano muchas gracias. Adjunto parametros que recibe la funcion:

```
[3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 16], [4, 10, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

La función pasada a `reduce` debe devolver el siguiente valor que tendrá acc. En este caso debería ser la lista original.

Lo que hace tu código es esto:

1. En el primer caso, funciona perfecto, ya que acc es una lista vacía. Agrega num a la lista y el lambda devuelve None, ya que el método append devuelve None.
2. Eso significa que el siguiente valor de acc será None, num si está en la segunda lista, por lo que el lambda devuelve acc, que por cierto sigue siendo None.
3. Aquí empieza el problema. El siguiente valor (7) no está en la segunda lista, por lo que intenta hacer el append. Pero como acc es None y la nada misma no tiene el atributo append, ocurre el error.

#### Solución

El lambda no sirve para este escenario, tendrás que hacer una función que haga a la lista los cambios correspondientes (si es que hay que hacerlos) y SIEMPRE devolver esa lista.

```
def notengo(lista_persona1, lista_persona2):
    def func_auxiliar(acc, num):
        if(num not in lista_persona2):
             acc.append(num)
        return acc

    return reduce(func_auxiliar, lista_persona1, list([]))
```

#### Conclusión

En este escenario particular, el uso de reduce no es una buena alternativa, ya que nos obliga a tener un código menos claro y usar una función auxiliar.

Lo mejor en este caso es usar una [comprensión de lista](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/).

Aun así, por motivos de aprendizaje decidí responder a la duda usando reduce.

Comment: Que interesante aporte.

Comment: Gracias Weizman c:

Comment: Comprendo lo que dices, lo intente porque en React lo que haces es "(acc, num)=> {'aqui va codigo'}". Gracias por despejar mi duda